# Can't find the correct version of Ruby for Vim without Cream

Tags: ruby, vim

I got Vim without Cream 7.3.744 from here http://sourceforge.net/projects/cream/files/Vim/.
When I look at `:help ruby-dynamic` it says:

```
You need to install the right version of Ruby for this to
work.  You can find the package to download from:
http://www.garbagecollect.jp/ruby/mswin32/en/download/release.html
Currently that is ruby-1.9.1-p429-i386-mswin32.zip

Currently the name is "msvcrt-ruby191.dll".

The name of the DLL must match the Ruby version Vim was
compiled with.  Currently the name is "msvcrt-ruby191.dll".
That is for Ruby 1.9.1.  To know for sure edit "gvim.exe" and
search for "ruby\d*.dll\c".
```

But it doesn't work with ruby-1.9.1-p429-i386-mswin32.zip, `:echo has('ruby')` returns 0.

When I look in gvim.exe, it says the dll is `msvcrt-ruby19.dll`, notice `19.dll` not `191.dll`. But I can't find a version of Ruby that includes that file. Even Ruby 1.9.0 has a dll called `msvcrt-ruby190.dll`. I tried just renaming the dll, but it just results in another error, namely:

```
LoadError: incompatible library version - 
C:/Program Files/Ruby19/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i386-mingw32/socket.so
```

Where can I find the correct version of Ruby? Or can I solve this some other way?

Comment: Did you try with any of [these](http://www.garbagecollect.jp/ruby/mswin32/en/download/develop.html)? Also why don't you simply use the official GVim distribution? It will probably work with whatever version of Ruby you have on your machine.

Comment: I don't actually know why, but the official vim installer together with Ruby is very slow. Also, it does not have +profile, so it's hard to find out why. And yes I tried most of them old rubies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got into contact with a developer of Cream without Vim, and he said:

> Sorry, took a closer look and fixed all this with a variable value
>   adjustment. Please try the latest build and confirm if it fixed your
>   issue:
>
> http://sourceforge.net/projects/cream/files/Vim/7.3.762/

And it seems to work. Although for some reason, when I'm trying to use [vim-foreplay](https://github.com/tpope/vim-foreplay) which uses Ruby, Ruby 1.9 with the official installer, and this new version of Vim without Cream with Ruby 1.9 is much slower than Ruby 1.8 together with Vim without Cream 7.3.289. Using vim-foreplay with the last mentioned version is instant, while both the two others require 1 second to eval code, and 2 seconds to set up a connection.